# In C#, is there a way to enforce use of "this/base" qualification in instance members?

Tags: c#, this, stylecop

Sometimes it can be confusing reading code in instance members that refers to other instance members of the same class (or a base class):

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    Where = did + AllTheseWeirdThings(GetDeclared()); // ?
}
```

Having a coding standard something like "prefix all private/protected members with "_" doesn't help, because instance members can still refer to public members.

It would be much better to read this:

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    this.Where = this.did + base.AllTheseWeirdThings(this.GetDeclared()); // ?
}
```

Is there a way to enforce this, either with compiler options, StyleCop, or something similar?

Comment: I used to do this but eventually I found it to be less helpful than the noise it creates.

Comment: I turned on this ReSharper warning, and found it incredibly annoying. It turns out it's rare to confuse class members with locals, and the `this.`/`base.` is usually redundant.

Comment: Stylecop has a rule for `this` prefix, but not for base. And it's also **on** by default.

Comment: As has been mentioned, StyleCop will do the trick, but I'd like to mention that you *should not do this*.

Comment: @Tim: If you use a leading underbar on fields, then it's impossible to confuse them with locals. Instead, you can reuse the same word, changing only the format. The constructor might take `userName` and assign `_userName`. If there were a property, it would be `UserName`.

Comment: Some context for this question: Whether or not this/base qualification is a good idea, it absolutely does make large legacy codebases more readable. We're not talking about making spaghetti, we're talking about understanding other people's spaghetti. Untangling the spaghetti is another discussion entirely. :)

Comment: @Colo: What makes bad code better can make good code worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no compiler option that enforces your rule.

However, a cursory Google search brings up this StyleCop rule: http://www.thewayithink.co.uk/stylecop/sa1101.htm

ReSharper has a similar option.

Comment: @yodaj007: Same way the rest of us did: on SO.

Answer (score 4):

In C# this and base are optional. The only time you *need* to use them (in this context) is if there is an ambiguity. There is no compiler switch to change this behaviour.

I'd also suggest *not* adding the StyleCop rule. It's generally better to only use this and base when you have to, for example in a constructor you might write:

```
this.foo = foo;
```

Enforcing usage of the "this" and "base" keywords won't make the code any better quality, or any more readable. If your code is so confusing that you can't figure out where members are defined I'd suggest refactoring it and making your class heirarchy simpler.

Comment: Fields are typically distinguished, as by a leading underbar, just to *avoid* the need for `this.`. So, yes, I agree that this is not a rule we would want.

Comment: Sometimes using "this" and "base" makes the code worse quality. Using the original example, if it becomes necessary to make base.AllTheseWeirdThings() virtual, you now have to search through your code to remove your calls to base.AllTheseWeirdThings(), or more likely, you forget until something doesn't work. That's actually the reason why I stopped using this/base the way it's being suggested.

Comment: @Joel: I'd say it *often* makes things worse.

Comment: I agree it's better to refactor code that's confusing and make class hierarchies more shallow. However, sometimes it's hard to refactor large legacy codebases without management's blessing. I often have too much other work to do. :)

Comment: @Colo: If the code is in need of refactoring but you don't refactor it, then the expected consequence is that development slows down and defect rate increases. In other words, if you're "too busy" to fix things, you will get even busier, and not in any productive way.

Comment: @Steven: Tell that to my boss and his boss. ;-)  Technical debt is called "debt" because sometimes the business wants to carry short-term debt to achieve some long-term goal. It doesn't mean I have to like it, but this is reality.

Comment: @Colonel: I'll be glad to, since I'm in a position to tell them the truth without getting fired for it. Technical debt is called "technical" because it's hard for non-technical people to evaluate. As a result, they typically fail to recognize its full extent, and therefore get in over their heads. If you let them do that, of course, you'll get the full blame when the debt slows your development speed to a crawl.